# What are those silicone blobs inside trackpad buttons?

Tags: laptop, touchpad, laptop-repair

I’m currently trying to fix up a fairly old computer where one of the trackpad buttons is actually missing the little silicone membrane that lets it register clicks. It seems like there’s a little magnet or conductor on the membrane for the other button. I’m trying to find replacements online and have so far not been too lucky. When I’m searching online for it what do you think I should search? I’ve tried *touchpad button membrane* and that just came up with a bunch of keyboards. Also, if anyone knows websites or suppliers that would stock them that would be very helpful.

Comment: Look for (pc keyboard) rubber cup. Could be that you will have a hard time finding the right ones tho. You might be able to cut one out of an old TV remote.

Comment: I wonder if the [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) stack would be a good place to ask that question.